# Можно ли назвать сборку многомодульной

Tags: c#, .net

Могу ли я назвать сборку многомодульной если в ней несколько пространств имен или я подключаю другую сборку.Если нет то могли привести примеры

Comment: что такое модуль в вашем понимании?

Comment: Артем добавил немного слов автору.

Comment: Троелсена читали?

Comment: [Module](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.module). И далее по ссылкам.

Answer (score 3):

Нет, несколько пространств имен тут ни о чем не говорит, и подключение других сборок тоже. По спецификации CLI понятие "модуль" имеет строго определенное значение - это файл, содержащий исполняемый код (ECMA-335 I.5)

> module: A single file containing content that can be executed by the VES.

Но вот понятие "многомодульная сборка" является многозначным. Под этим могут понимать:

1. Сборку, состоящую из нескольких физических файлов (такую сборку также называют [многофайловой](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/multifile-assemblies))
2. Сборку, полученную [компоновкой нескольких файлов .netmodule в один физический файл](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/netmodule-files-as-linker-input?view=vs-2019)

Многофайловые сборки получают, подавая на вход программы Assembly Linker (al.exe) нескольких файлов .netmodule. В результате получается сборка, которая содержит манифест примерно такого вида:

```
.module extern Client.netmodule

(...)

.assembly myAssembly
{
  .hash algorithm 0x00008004
  .ver 0:0:0:0
}
.file Client.netmodule
    .hash = (03 DB 59 BE DA B5 E9 DB 7E 0E D3 E5 2E AB 76 2A   // ..Y.....~.....v*
             73 C6 99 82 )                                     // s...
.file Stringer.netmodule
    .hash = (95 BF 9C ED 5F 64 B5 66 5A D3 2F 7D 6A EF E9 76   // ...._d.fZ./}j..v
             B3 E0 B8 67 )                                     // ...g
.class extern public myStringer.Stringer
{
  .file Stringer.netmodule
  .class 0x02000002
}

(...)
```

То есть здесь сборка myAssembly.exe сама не содержит кода, а ссылается на два внешних файла модулей, Client.netmodule и Stringer.netmodule. Чтобы ее запустить и выполнить код из файла .netmodule, этот файл должен лежать с ней в одном месте, в противном случае будет ошибка.

Сборки второго вида получают, подавая на вход обычного компоновщика Visual C++ (link.exe) несколько файлов .netmodule. В результате получается один физический файл, содержащий объединенный код из всех этих модулей. При этом на уровне метаданных не будет никаких признаков, что сборка собиралась из нескольких модулей. Практический смысл тут в том, чтобы сочетать в одной сборке код на разных языках программирования. По слухам, PresentationCore в WPF сделана именно таким образом, из одного модуля на C# и второго - на С++/CLI.

Если же вы получили сборку с помощью обычной компиляции C# в Visual Studio или командной строке MSBuild, без компоновки, то она не может быть ни многомодульной, ни многофайловой.

Comment: Смысл у них один и тот же получается,но есть 2 варианта хранения, в первом модули многофайловой сборке находятся,как отдельные файлы, в одной папке с исполняемым файлом,а в другом варианте они уже включены,к примеру в тот же самый исполняемый файл и представлены одним файлом?

Comment: @n_enrai49 Да, все правильно. У первого варианта есть еще один дополнительный смысл, не грузить в память полный код сборки, если он весь не нужен, так как внешние модули грузятся в память только при первой попытке вызвать код из этого модуля.

Comment: Я попробовал немного "поковыряться"  и вот что получилось:в одном пространстве имен я объявил базовый класс и его класс-наследник, классы сохранились в разные файлы "cs", через командную строку я сделал каждого из них отдельными модулями(.netmodule), и создал главный модуль формата dll,не имеющего кода,но имеющего манифест, получилась сборка.Так вот можно ли ее многомодульной и многофайловой?

Comment: @n_enrai49 Можно. Ответ об этом и говорит.

Comment: Просто я то же самое могу сделать и просто через сборку решения в Visual Studio,получается все сборки по своей сути многомодульные,только они полученные компоновкой нескольких файлов в один физический?

Comment: @n_enrai49 Нет, Visual Studio генерирует однофайловую сборку. Этапа компоновки там нет, даже внутренне, и .netmodule тоже нет, csc выплевывает сразу exe/dll файл с кодом всех .cs файлов проекта. Если бы это было не так, для сборки проекта на C# требовалось бы установить Visual C++.

Comment: Но я ведь могу сделать то же самое

Comment: Прошу прощения за навязчивость,можно ли сказать,что средства Visual Studio берут код из файлов проекта .cs,и компилирует это все в один единый модуль?

Comment: @n_enrai49 Да. Именно это я и написал в предыдущем комментарии.